# How to access CoreData in a single swift UI view with in the UIKit Project

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an Project that I developed in UIKit but now slowly migrating to Swift UI ..I have written all my CoreData logic before now I want to access CoreData context in my Swift UI...

Here Adding Swift UI view like below from viewcontroller

```
    let swiftUIView = ListView(date: self.date, context: context, userSession: userSession, scheduleViewModel: viewModel)
    addSubSwiftUIView(swiftUIView, to: containerView)
```

Swift UI view here

```
struct ListView: View {
    let date: Date
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    let userSession: UserSessionTrait
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {}
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            FilteredList(date: date, context: context, userSession: userSession) { (appointment: Appointment) in
                ScheduleRowView(appointment: appointment)
                    .id(appointment)
            }
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
    }
  }

struct FilteredList<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {
    @FetchRequest var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<Appointment>

    // this is our content closure; we'll call this once for each item in the list
    let content: (Appointment) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        List(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { appointment in
            self.content(appointment)
        }
    }

    init(date: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext, userSession: UserSessionTrait, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Appointment) -> Content) {
        _fetchRequest = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Appointment.sortedFetchRequest(in: context, userId: userSession.userId, date: date))
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

But when I load this app is crashing with bad access and it's slowing down as well bacz of this line  **.environment(.managedObjectContext, context)** SO my Q

1. is it possible to access CoreData lime this in non-swiftUi project
2. is there any workaround for this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)`, you never initialize `context` in your code and normally this code line exists on the parent view or the topmost view. You should do some research on using core data with SwiftUI, there are plenty of articles around

Comment: I am initializing from viewController updated my Q thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the context from UIKit into the SwiftUI environment. You can see it in the old Xcode SwiftUI Core Data template (I believe v12) before we had SwiftUI App life cycle (I don't have that handy sorry). It's also in [this Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9335365-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-getting-started).

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
let contentView = MovieList().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

Also I recommend getting rid of your view model objects, we don't use those in SwiftUI. The View data struct is the model for the UIKit views that SwiftUI generates. And given its a value type we eliminate bugs that can occur with objects. If you add objects on top then you risk adding the bugs that SwiftUI was designed to
eliminate.

There is a tip in the FetchRequest header you might find handy:

```
/// If you need to separate the request and the result
/// entities, you can declare `quakes` in two steps by
/// using the request's `wrappedValue` to obtain the results:
///
///     var fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Quake>(fetchRequest: request)
///     var quakes: FetchedResults<Quake> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
```

So you don't have to use the property wrapper `@FetchRequest` and can use `FetchRequest` just as a dynamic property. In dynamic properties, the `update` func is called before body is run, which is how `FetchRequest` retrieves the context from the environment.

So for example you could do:

```
private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Appointment>
private var appointments: FetchedResults<Appointment> {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue
}

init(date: Date) {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest( // use date
}
```

Comment: I am passing context from viewController to swift UI view already (updated Q). but still facing same issue.